Python pypdf watermark position
I am trying to add a watermark to a pdf using pypdf. I have a watermark.pdf file which has 'Confidential' in small read font on the very top left of the page. However when I try to stamp or watermark 'Confidential' to 'in.pdf', the resulting out.pdf places 'Confidential' further down than where it is in the watermark.pdf file and therefore making it clash with the content in the in.pdf file. How can I ensure that the 'Confidential' watermark stays on the very top left of the page where it is out of the way of the main content?
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

stamp = PdfReader("watermark.pdf").pages[0]
writer = PdfWriter(clone_from="in.pdf")
for page in writer.pages:
    page.merge_page(stamp, over=True)  # here set to False for watermarking

writer.write("out.pdf")

